# If Play! automatically starts a transacton for every request and manages it, why put @Transactional on method?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework, transactions

According to the Play! docs, it automatically creates a transaction for every request whether you want it or not:

> Play will automatically manage transactions for you. It will start a transaction for each HTTP request and commit it when the HTTP response is sent. If your code throws an exception, the transaction will automatically rollback.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/jpa

Given that, what is the point of the `@Transactional` annotation? It doesn't turn on a transaction, as the docs indicate transactions are already on.

The docs for the later Play! framework (2.5) seem to contradict this statement, saying that without `@Transactional` your JPA method calls will violate the requirement that they all occur within a transaction:

> Every JPA call must be done in a transaction so, to enable JPA for a particular action, annotate it with @play.db.jpa.Transactional.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA

```
@Transactional
public Result index() {
    return ok("A Transactional action");
}
```

Which is it? Does your method, if called from an HTTP context not run in a transaction unless that annotation is used?

And if you change the transaction isolation level (in conf), does that mean every single call will be in that level transaction, or only `@Transactional` methods?

Comment: I'm using Play 2.4 and there I have to use @Transactional. Otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Kris What do you mean "it wouldn't work"?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that without the annotation @Transactional Play would throw an exception if I do some JPA stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two very different Play versions (like Angular 1 and 2). For example, Play 1.x is built on Java while Play 2.x is built on Scala and provides Scala+Java API's. So there is no contradictions in the docs, I think.

In Play 1:

- Transactions are managed automatically
- You can use annotations to change this: ex `@play.db.jpa.NoTransaction` to disable the transaction

In Play 2:

- No "automatic" transactions;
- You have to use `@Transactional` to get "automatic" transactions (the default behavior in Play 1)

Regarding the "transaction isolation level (in conf)", I can't say anything because I have never used it (can you show an example?), but I guess it will apply that isolation level to every action annotated with `@Transactional` or other JPA methods (ex `JPAApi.withTransaction`)

Comment: Thank you, so does this mean in 1.x, I cannot start and commit a transaction manually? No matter what, the transaction will be started on a request?

Comment: Also, since in 1.x, it handles transactions automatically, what's the purpose of `JPA.startTx(boolean readonly);`? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/api/play/db/jpa/JPA.html#startTx-java.lang.String-boolean-

Comment: By default no, it will always start a transaction for you. But if you dont want that behavior annotate that method/class with `@play.db.jpa.NoTransaction` and it will no start any trans. for you in that method/every method of the class.

Comment: Forget what I said about controllers. `JPA.startTx` allows you to control the transaction when you  want to manage it manually (ex: only roll-backing on exception may not be what you want)

Comment: but if Play automatically starts a transaction when a request is started, then dies that mean JPA.startTx is starting a nested transaction? Or something else?

Comment: I have never done that, but I guess it would do something like calling `JPA.startTx` twice...

Comment: Thanks. It's just odd as we've tagged our method as `@Transactional` but we're still getting some race condition that leads to incorrect data in the MySQL db. Since everything is in a transaction, not sure what's causing it.